# My output is not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

So in HTML file I am taking in 6 numbers which will be used to determine the derivative for a user input amount of time. And this is the code that I have for the HTML

```
<body>
    <h1>Enter your numbers:</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <h4>Enter your first number:</h4><input type="text" name="firstNum" id="first">
            <h4>Enter your second number:</h4><input type="text" name="secondNum" id="second">
            <h4>Enter your third number:</h4><input type="text" name="thirdNum" id="third">
            <h4>Enter your fourth number:</h4><input type="text" name="fourthNum" id "fourth">
            <h4>Enter your fifth number:</h4><input type="text" name="fifthNum" id="fifth">
            <h4>Enter your sixth number:</h4><input type="text" name="sixthNum" id="sixth">
            <h4>Enter the number of rows:</h4><input type="text" name="rowsNum" id="rows">
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>y</th>
            <th>&#9651y</th>
            <th>&#9651<sup>2</sup>y</th>
            <th>&#9651<sup>3</sup>y</th>
            <th>&#9651<sup>4</sup>y</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick="submitForCalc()">Submit</button>
    <div id="tablePrint"> </div>

    <script src="babbCore.js"> </script>
</body>
```

And in my js file I have

```
function submitForCalc()
 {
/*
    If no inputs are given the defaults will be 0
*/
var firstInput = 0;
var secondInput =0;
var thirdInput =0;
var fourthInput =0;
var fifthInput =0;
var sixthInput =0;
var rowInput = 1;

/*
    Stores the user inputs into the values
*/
firstInput = document.getElementById("first").value; 
secondInput = document.getElementById("second").value;
thirdInput = document.getElementById("third").value;
fourthInput = document.getElementById("fourth").value;
fifthInput = document.getElementById("fifth").value;
sixthInput = document.getElementById("sixth").value;
rowInput = document.getElementById("rows").value;

/*
    stores the answer for each derivative into an array
*/
var zeroDir = new Array();
var firstDir = new Array();
var secondDir = new Array();
var thirdDir = new Array();
var fourthDir = new Array();
var fifthDir = new Array();

var myTable = "<table style="width:100%><tr>";  //the table of outputs

//This is where the calculations are done
var i =0;
for (i; i<rowInput; i++)
{
    zeroDir[i] = (firstInput*Math.pow(i, 5))+(secondInput*Math.pow(i, 4))+(thirdInput*Math.pow(i, 3))+(fourthInput*Math.pow(i, 2))+(fifthInput*Math.pow(i, 1))+sixthInput;
    firstDir[i] = ((5*firstInput)*Math.pow(i, 4))+((4*secondInput)*Math.pow(i, 3))+((3*thirdInput)*Math.pow(i, 2))+((2*fourthInput)*Math.pow(i, 1))+fifthInput;
    secondDir[i] = ((20*firstInput)*Math.pow(i, 3))+((12*secondInput)*Math.pow(i, 2))+((6*thirdInput)*Math.pow(i, 1))+(2*fourthInput);
    thirdDir[i] = ((60*firstInput)*Math.pow(i, 2))+((24*secondInput)*Math.pow(i, 1))+(6*thirdInput);
    fourthDir[i] = ((120*firstInput)*Math.pow(i, 1))+(24*secondInput);
    fifthDir[i] = (120*firstInput);
}

//This is where the output is created
for (var j=0; j<i; j++) 
{
    myTable += "<th>"+zeroDir[j] + "</th>"+ "<th>"+firstDir[j] +"</th>"+ "<th>"+secondDir[j] + "</th>"+ "<th>"+thirdDir[j] + "</th>"+ "<th>" + fourthDir[j] + "</th>" + "<th>" +fifthDir[j]+ "</th>";
} 
myTable+="</tr></table>";
document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = myTable;
}
```

I have everything set.  When the user enters all the numbers the first to the fifth derivative will be calculated and stored into an array.  After all the calculations are done it will then insert all the outputs into a table where it will be displayed in a table format.  I used an alert to test weather or not my function was being called, and it was not.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: typo: when definig var myTable change the double quotes which enclose width to single quote `var myTable = "<table style='width:100%'><tr>";`

Comment: I changed the myTable part and for the rowInput, would it be just rowInput.length or rowInput.length() ?

Comment: @RickBronger I don't think `rowInput` is an array so no need for `.length` I believe `rowInput` is the value of an input which should be have `rowInput = parseInt(document.getElementById("rows").value);` to parse the value as an in integer only.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The primary change is, as wrote in a comment in the question, to change the definition of the table variable

```
 var myTable = "<table style='width:100%'><tr>";
```

Coding on snippet i also had to change another line, but i was not able to find it again looking at the question, so i guess it was a problem with copy/paste.

Than it was everything working itself.

Sorry for delay adding details, but i was not here.

**edit 2**
The second problem was the definition in the html of `<input type="text" name="fourthNum" id "fourth">`. It was missing the `=`, so that i placed

The error got before this change was "trying to get property value of null", since off course it was impossible to find an element with id **fourth** before the edit.

```js
function submitForCalc() {
  /*
      If no inputs are given the defaults will be 0
  */
  var firstInput = 0;
  var secondInput = 0;
  var thirdInput = 0;
  var fourthInput = 0;
  var fifthInput = 0;
  var sixthInput = 0;
  var rowInput = 1;

  /*
      Stores the user inputs into the values
  */
  firstInput = document.getElementById("first").value;
  secondInput = document.getElementById("second").value;
  thirdInput = document.getElementById("third").value;
  fourthInput = document.getElementById("fourth").value;
  fifthInput = document.getElementById("fifth").value;
  sixthInput = document.getElementById("sixth").value;
  rowInput = document.getElementById("rows").value;

  /*
      stores the answer for each derivative into an array
  */
  var zeroDir = new Array();
  var firstDir = new Array();
  var secondDir = new Array();
  var thirdDir = new Array();
  var fourthDir = new Array();
  var fifthDir = new Array();

  var myTable = "<table style='width:100%'><tr>"; //the table of outputs

  //This is where the calculations are done
  var i = 0;
  for (i; i < rowInput; i++) {
    zeroDir[i] = (firstInput * Math.pow(i, 5)) + (secondInput * Math.pow(i, 4)) + (thirdInput * Math.pow(i, 3)) + (fourthInput * Math.pow(i, 2)) + (fifthInput * Math.pow(i, 1)) + sixthInput;
    firstDir[i] = ((5 * firstInput) * Math.pow(i, 4)) + ((4 * secondInput) * Math.pow(i, 3)) + ((3 * thirdInput) * Math.pow(i, 2)) + ((2 * fourthInput) * Math.pow(i, 1)) + fifthInput;
    secondDir[i] = ((20 * firstInput) * Math.pow(i, 3)) + ((12 * secondInput) * Math.pow(i, 2)) + ((6 * thirdInput) * Math.pow(i, 1)) + (2 * fourthInput);
    thirdDir[i] = ((60 * firstInput) * Math.pow(i, 2)) + ((24 * secondInput) * Math.pow(i, 1)) + (6 * thirdInput);
    fourthDir[i] = ((120 * firstInput) * Math.pow(i, 1)) + (24 * secondInput);
    fifthDir[i] = (120 * firstInput);
  }

  //This is where the output is created
  for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    myTable += "<th>" + zeroDir[j] + "</th>" + "<th>" + firstDir[j] + "</th>" + "<th>" + secondDir[j] + "</th>" + "<th>" + thirdDir[j] + "</th>" + "<th>" + fourthDir[j] + "</th>" + "<th>" + fifthDir[j] + "</th>";
  }
  myTable += "</tr></table>";
  document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = myTable;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Enter your numbers:</h1>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <h4>Enter your first number:</h4>
      <input type="text" name="firstNum" id="first">
      <h4>Enter your second number:</h4>
      <input type="text" name="secondNum" id="second">
      <h4>Enter your third number:</h4>
      <input type="text" name="thirdNum" id="third">
      <h4>Enter your fourth number:</h4>
      <input type="text" name="fourthNum" id="fourth">
      <h4>Enter your fifth number:</h4>
      <input type="text" name="fifthNum" id="fifth">
      <h4>Enter your sixth number:</h4>
      <input type="text" name="sixthNum" id="sixth">
      <h4>Enter the number of rows:</h4>
      <input type="text" name="rowsNum" id="rows">
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>y</th>
      <th>&#9651y</th>
      <th>&#9651<sup>2</sup>y</th>
      <th>&#9651<sup>3</sup>y</th>
      <th>&#9651<sup>4</sup>y</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" onclick="submitForCalc()">Submit</button>
  <div id="tablePrint"></div>

  <script src="babbCore.js">
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: The least you could do is explain the changes you have made and give reason to why... Not everyone just wants the source code fixing, some would like to know why it wasn't functioning as intended to learn from that mistake for future reference.

Comment: @Hulu I think the only change is `var myTable = "<table style="width:100%><tr>";`  To this  `var myTable = "<table style='width:100%'><tr>";` Which uses single quotes to stop the string breaking from the styles attribute. Why GiuServ hasn't added a detailed explanation to this is beyond me. No doubt just one of those who dump a solution to get marked but fails to understand people like to understand the problem and learn from it.

Comment: Sorry, yes, i added now the details, i was a bit busy after tested and saved the snippet. I also found out the other problem that i'm gonna add in my answer (it's the definition of `id "fourth"`)

Answer (score 0):

Few things here

1. Never mix your markup with javascript
2. Try binding events at javascript end
3. Dont write strings as "".Make use of createElement and insertRows
4. Break down your code into multiple methods/subroutines it is diffilcut to understand if it takes more than 10 lines

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
  submit.addEventListener('click', submitForCalc);
}

function submitForCalc() {

  var firstInput = 0;
  var secondInput = 0;
  var thirdInput = 0;
  var fourthInput = 0;
  var fifthInput = 0;
  var sixthInput = 0;
  var rowInput = 1;

  firstInput = document.getElementById("first").value;

  secondInput = document.getElementById("second").value;

  thirdInput = document.getElementById("third").value;

  var fourthInput = document.getElementById("fourth").value;

  fifthInput = document.getElementById("fifth").value;

  sixthInput = document.getElementById("sixth").value;

  rowInput = document.getElementById("rows").value;


  /*
      stores the answer for each derivative into an array
  */
  var zeroDir = new Array();
  var firstDir = new Array();
  var secondDir = new Array();
  var thirdDir = new Array();
  var fourthDir = new Array();
  var fifthDir = new Array();

  var myTable = document.createElement('table');
  myTable.style.width = "100%";
  myTable.style.border = "1";
  var i = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < rowInput; i++) {
    zeroDir[i] = (firstInput * Math.pow(i, 5)) + (secondInput * Math.pow(i, 4)) + (thirdInput * Math.pow(i, 3)) + (fourthInput * Math.pow(i, 2)) + (fifthInput * Math.pow(i, 1)) + sixthInput;
    firstDir[i] = ((5 * firstInput) * Math.pow(i, 4)) + ((4 * secondInput) * Math.pow(i, 3)) + ((3 * thirdInput) * Math.pow(i, 2)) + ((2 * fourthInput) * Math.pow(i, 1)) + fifthInput;
    secondDir[i] = ((20 * firstInput) * Math.pow(i, 3)) + ((12 * secondInput) * Math.pow(i, 2)) + ((6 * thirdInput) * Math.pow(i, 1)) + (2 * fourthInput);
    thirdDir[i] = ((60 * firstInput) * Math.pow(i, 2)) + ((24 * secondInput) * Math.pow(i, 1)) + (6 * thirdInput);
    fourthDir[i] = ((120 * firstInput) * Math.pow(i, 1)) + (24 * secondInput);
    fifthDir[i] = (120 * firstInput);


  }
  var header = myTable.createTHead();
  var row = header.insertRow(0);
  //This is where the output is created
  for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    var thElement_1 = document.createElement('th');
    thElement_1.innerHTML = zeroDir[j];

    row.appendChild(thElement_1);

    var thElement_2 = document.createElement('th');
    thElement_2.innerHTML = firstDir[j];

    row.appendChild(thElement_2);

    var thElement_3 = document.createElement('th');
    thElement_3.innerHTML = secondDir[j];

    row.appendChild(thElement_3);
    var thElement_4 = document.createElement('th');
    thElement_4.innerHTML = thirdDir[j];

    row.appendChild(thElement_4);
    var thElement_5 = document.createElement('th');
    thElement_5.innerHTML = fourthDir[j];

    row.appendChild(thElement_5);

  }

  var printTable = document.getElementById('tablePrint');
  printTable.append(myTable);
}
```

```html
 <h1>Enter your numbers:</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <h4>Enter your first number:</h4>
    <input type="text" name="firstNum" id="first">
    <h4>Enter your second number:</h4>
    <input type="text" name="secondNum" id="second">
    <h4>Enter your third number:</h4>
    <input type="text" name="thirdNum" id="third">
    <h4>Enter your fourth number:</h4>
    <input type="text" name="fourthNum" id="fourth">
    <h4>Enter your fifth number:</h4>
    <input type="text" name="fifthNum" id="fifth">
    <h4>Enter your sixth number:</h4>
    <input type="text" name="sixthNum" id="sixth">
    <h4>Enter the number of rows:</h4>
    <input type="text" name="rowsNum" id="rows">
  </tr>
</table>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>y</th>
    <th>&#9651y</th>
    <th>&#9651<sup>2</sup>y</th>
    <th>&#9651<sup>3</sup>y</th>
    <th>&#9651<sup>4</sup>y</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="button" id="submit" >Submit</button>
<div id="tablePrint"></div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'll keep what you said in mind.  I usually code in c++ or java, and am trying out some web development. It's not as easy as it looks.  Appreciate your input, thanks.